# does this yield convergence to smooth limit function?

Tags: calculus

let $u: M \times [0,T) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $M$ compact Riemannian manifold (but would also be helpful first to just consider compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$), and $u$ smooth as a function of $M$ for all times $t < T$.

Assume $u(.,t)$ converges uniformly to continuous limit function $u(.,T)$.

If it is possible to show the covariant (partial if considering K) derivatives of any order along $M$ of $u$ stay uniformly bounded for all times $t < T$, is that sufficient to obtain $u(.,T)$ is also smooth as a function of $M$? And if so, what theorem guarantees this?

Comment: Taking a look at the Sobolev embedding theorem, it may be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality  I think you are going to need the derivatives of all orders to be bounded.

Comment: ah yes that was terribly written by me. with 'all derivatives' i meant derivatives up to any order, ill edit this in the original post